# byte[] to UTF8 Encoding not working properly

Tags: c#, utf-8

I have a requirement where I need to read network stream data, generate response and write the response back to stream. I am using below code for that purpose:

```
var bufferData = new byte[] { 00, 00, 00, 175 }; //Byte buffer read from stream
var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bufferData); //Generate response
var responseByte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encoding); //Bytes to write
```

However, the byte array generated in last step is not the same as the "*bufferData*". I get response byte as `[0, 0, 0, 239, 191, 189]` which is not same as the input data. Need help in figuring out what wrong I am doing.

Comment: @mjwills: I need to write http response back to network stream. Response needs to have ID from request. I read the ID from request, generate response, and then write to network stream. Only that ID gets changed when I do the conversion as above.

Comment: You encode that byte array to string and than back but to UTF-8. The UTF-8 storage length is larger than the a byte storage so 175 ==> 239, 191, 189.

Comment: @mjwills: If I wasn't clear before, those bytes represent the request ID. I need to covert them to string because my generated HTTP response is a string, where I need to add this ID and write back to response. I will edit my question to explain more.

Comment: I'll be clearer - those bytes do not represent a valid UTF8 string. Read the duplicate link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The byte sequence 239, 191, 189 is the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character FFFD or 'replacement character'. You get that because the 175 byte in your input isn't a valid character using UTF-8 encoding. It *is* a valid character using the iso-8859-1 codepage or other similar 8 bit codepages.

If you use the iso-8859-1 codepage, you get the same data after the transformation

```
      var bufferData = new byte[] { 00, 00, 00, 175 }; //Byte buffer read from stream
      var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(bufferData); //Generate response
      var responseByte = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(encoding);
```